# C#/XNA XML serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, xna

First time using serialization in XNA so forgive me if I'm over looking soemthing obvious.

Basically, in my game, I have two objects, Square (storing data about each square in the game) and one called Enemy (storing information and behaviours about the enemey).

I want to serialize this data so I can save and load it in at a later date.

I've put them both into a single object called Data and serialised that.

However the xml data reads like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <squares>
    <Square />
    <Square />
    <Square />
    <Square />
    <Square />
    <Square />
    <Square />
    <Square />
    <Square />
```

etc

My code:

```
Data.cs
public class Data
    {       
       public Square[] squares;
       public Enemy[] enemies;

       public Data()
        {

        }
    }
```

SaveFucntion:

```
    Data data = new Data();
    data.squares = squares;
    data.enemies = enemies;
    StreamWriter file2 = new StreamWriter(Content.RootDirectory + "\\xml.txt");
    XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Data));
    x.Serialize(file2, data);
```

What am I doing wrong? or what would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Does `Square` have public properties? The `XmlSerializer` serializes public properties only. If you want more control, take a look at the `DataContractSerializer`.

Comment: the quickest solution for you would be to add `{get;set;}` to the end of your fields like Nico said `public Square[] Squares {get;set;}`

Comment: @Sayse: No, `XmlSerializer` can also serialize public fields. And as you see the `squares` array can be serialized, though the squares are empty. That's probably because the square class does not contain public fields or properties.